# Can you add a javascript callback listener to matchMedia on Android Chrome?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, listener, media-queries

I'm using matchMedia on a page and I've noticed that on Chrome for Android, the check for matches works, but when you try to add a listener to the media query, the callback function never fires.

I've run the same code on the desktop and it works fine, but it doesn't seem to call the callback in the listener on Android 4.x devices with Chrome as the browser. Has this not been implemented in the browser yet?

```
var width768Check = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)");
console.log(width768Check.matches);
console.log(width768Check.addListener);
width768Check.addListener(function(mediaQueryList) {
    console.log(mediaQueryList.matches);
});
```

**UPDATE**

I've been testing using a Nexus 7 tablet with Google Chrome v18.0.1025469 and Android v4.2.1 and a Asus Transformer tablet with the same version of Google Chrome and a different version of Android, v4.0.3.

The funny thing is that the Asus tablet uses the listener callback functions correctly and the Nexus 7 does not. I'm not sure why the same version of Chrome on a newer version of the Android operating system would cause issues. Also, for the Nexus 7, I downloaded Dolphin Browser and everything works fine.

Comment: According to this it has: http://caniuse.com/matchmedia

Comment: I know that Chrome on Android supports matchMedia, but the callback listener doesn't seem to be firing consistently.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the viewport display width to device pixel, the size of the screen is 601x880 pixels, which is scaled down based on the devicepixel density (1.3 on a N7)

This would explain what you are seeing and as can be seen in the test here: http://jsbin.com/eyorap/latest

When you don't set the viewport width, even though screen.width reports 601, the media query will match because it should be using the actual device width. See this demo: http://jsbin.com/igifon

Answer (score 0):

I've also met this issue and found - at least in the web - an interesting proposal for a workaround:

[media query listener for WebKit](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/01/19/css-media-queries-in-javascript-part-2/)

And I've tested this solution on an iPhone 4S with Chrome, and (important!) on a Samsung Galaxy Nexus (or so) with Chrome, too, and it worked.

It is a bit ugly, but I've found it better than waiting for well working orientationchange events (on document or screen).

Answer (score 0):

You could try the light weight **[Enquire .js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/)** library. It handle's call backs on match and unmatch + an initial optional function. It seems to work well on Android devices with the Chrome browser, but I'm currently having difficulty triggering orientation matches on the Native browser.

Also: Paul Irish has his own **[implementation](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js)** for matchMedia.